# Android Geofencing dosen't trigger IntentService

Tags: java, android, google-api-client, geofencing, android-geofence

I'm building a mobile application with which I'll be able to test working of geofencing on Android phones. I have an application that uses `GoogleApiClient` for `FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates`. I'm getting all the updates which I show on the map in my MapFragment. I then try to add the geofences with `GeofencingClient`.

```
private void addGeofenceList() {
    mGeofencingClient.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(), getGeofencePendingIntent())
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Log.wtf(TAG, "addGeofences() - succesfully added");
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.wtf(TAG, "addGeofences() - failed to add");
                }
            });
}
```

This code is executed and I get back that they were succesfully added. But when I'm on the location where the geofence should trigger it dosen't call the IntentService. I also add the IntentService:

```
private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceService.class);
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

I also create a `GeofencingRequest` where I set the initial trigger when entered.

```
private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
            .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
            .addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}
```

And this is where I create the `ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofenceList` in which I add all the geofences:

```
public void createGeofenceList() {
    GeofenceList geofences = new GeofenceList();
    ArrayList<GeofenceModel> geofenceList = (ArrayList) geofences.returnGeofences();
    for (GeofenceModel geofence : geofenceList) {
        mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId(geofence.getREQ_ID())
                .setCircularRegion(
                        geofence.getLocation().latitude,
                        geofence.getLocation().longitude,
                        geofence.getRadius()
                )
                .setExpirationDuration(geofence.getExpire())
                .setTransitionTypes(geofence.getTransition())
                .build());
    }
    addGeofenceList();
}
```

My whole projects is on [GitHub](https://github.com/cotnic/geofence-android). All the help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest replace your service declaration which is

`<service android:name="services.GeofenceService" />`

to this

`<service android:name="services.GeofenceService" 
          android:exported="true"/>`

Basically you should mark your service as `exported` so Android OS can invoke your `IntentService`